# Nested DAX Query

Tags: dax

Am an experienced SQL guy ... new to DAX.  I'm trying to create 
a DAX query to generate a moving average inventory.
The internals of the inventory calculation are a bit complicated, but
hopefully not necessary for this discussion.

Input would be like:

```
month   inventory
1        5
2        9
3        7
4        11
```

Desired output is:

```
reportMonth average3MthInventory
3           7
4           9
```

That is, the avg inventory to be reported for month 3 is the trailing
average of months 1,2,3 = (5+9+7) / 3 = 7 ... month 4 would be the
average of values for months 2,3,4.

So far, the query uses *summarize* to produce an intermediate table
of monthly inventory numbers i.e.

```
evaluate
filter(
  crossJoin(
    summarize(
      ...
        , reportMonths[month]   -- group by
      , "inventory", count(widgets[widgetID]) 
    ) -- end summarize
  ) -- end crossJoin
)  -- end filter
```

This produces an intermediate table:

```
reportMonths[month] actualMonths[month] [inventory] ... plus some other columns  
    3                   1                   5
    3                   2                   9
    3                   3                   7
    4                   2                   9
    4                   3                   7
    4                   4                   11
```

This is exactly as expected.  From this, should be able to average
the inventory over the report month.

At this point, I wrapped the query above in another *summarize* to
compute the final numbers:

```
evaluate
summarize(
  filter(
    crossJoin(
      summarize(
        ...
        , reportMonths[month]   -- group by
        , "inventory", count(widgets[widgetID]) 
      ) -- end summarize
    ) -- end crossJoin
  )  -- end filter
  , "month", reportMonths[month]
  , "avgInventory", average([inventory])
) -- summarize
```

But, this returns an error: "Cannot identify the table that contains [inventory] column."

Can't find a way to refer to the intermediate table.  There must be another way to structure this.

Any ideas appreciated.

---

Edit in response to Alejandro Zuleta:

Alejandro,

Thanks for the quick response.  Further info follows ...

Inventory history is built up from product "listings".  Date granularity is monthly and each listing has an onMarket month and offMarket month (months are numbered sequentially).  listings have other attributes typeID, areaID, etc.

```
listingID  onMarketMonth  offMarketMonth ... other attribs - typeID, etc.
101        1              2
103        1              6
105        2              2
106        2              
109        2              3
117        3              4
123        3              
124        3              9
```

Inventory is computed based on the onMarket and offMarket months e.g. in month 3 inventory is the number of listings where the onMarket month <= 3 and offMarket month is > 3 (or blank). Based on the table above, inventory would be as follows:

inventory

```
month   inventory   note: listings in inventory
1       2           101, 103
2       3           103, 106, 109
3       5           103, 106, 117, 123, 124
4       4           103, 106, 123, 124
```

...

Need to be able to report a series of values e.g. for a chart as well as moving averages.  Example code for a series of months 2 through 6 for a particular type and area would be :

```
evaluate
summarize(
    filter(
        crossJoin(
            calculateTable(listings, listings[typeID] = 47)
            , filter(reportMonths, [month] >= 2 && [month] <= 6 )
        ) -- crossjoin
        , listings[onMarketMonth] <= reportMonths[month] && (or(listings[offMarketMonth] > reportMonths[month], isBlank(listings[offMarketMonth]))) -- join condition
    ) -- filter the join
    , reportMonths[month]
    , "inventory",count(listings[listingID])
) -- summarize
```

This works.  The hangup is ... how to extend this to create a moving average inventory.

**Update**
Figured it out.  The key was switching from *summarize* to *groupBy*(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163693.aspx).

Notice in the sample code (below) that [Total Sales] is defined/calculated in the GroupBy in the VAR and then referenced in the query below (in the GroupBy in the Evaluate).  When I tried something similar using Summarize, got an error.

```
DEFINE  
VAR SalesByCountryAndCategory =  
GROUPBY (  
Sales,   
Geography[Country],   
Product[Category],   
“Total Sales”, SUMX( CURRENTGROUP(), Sales[Price] * Sales[Qty])  
)  

Evaluate GROUPBY (  
SalesByCountryAndCategory,   
Geography[Country],   
 “Max Sales”, MAXX( CURRENTGROUP(), [Total Sales])  
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a measure to get the desired average by using `EARLIER` function.

```
average3MthInventory =
IF (
    MAX ( [month] ) > 2,
    CALCULATE (
        AVERAGE ( Inventory[inventory] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Inventory[month] ),
            COUNTROWS (
                FILTER (
                    Inventory,
                    EARLIER ( [month] )
                        >= [month] - 2
                        && [month] >= EARLIER ( Inventory[month] )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

Then just use that measure in your pivot table or Power BI visualization.

[image]

However if you need to get a table you can use this expression:

```
EVALUATE
FILTER (
    SUMMARIZE (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                Inventory,
                "MinMonth", IF ( Inventory[month] > 2, Inventory[month] - 2, BLANK () )
            ),
            "average3MthInventory", IF (
                ISBLANK ( [MinMonth] ),
                BLANK (),
                CALCULATE (
                    AVERAGE ( Inventory[inventory] ),
                    FILTER (
                        Inventory,
                        [month] >= EARLIER ( [MinMonth] )
                            && [month] <= EARLIER ( [month] )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        [month],
        [average3MthInventory]
    ),
    NOT ISBLANK ( [average3MthInventory] )
)
```

Assuming your input table is called `Inventory` you should get this:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

The inventory table produced by your DAX expression cannot be processed to calculate the average of the last three months. Fortunately you are using SSAS 2016 which supports calculated tables.

Calculated tables are fully operable tables produced by a DAX expression against one or more tables in your model.

You have to create a calculated table using the DAX expression that produces the inventory per month. I recommend you to name it `Inventory` to match the DAX query I posted above to calculate the required average.

Check these resources about calculated tables creation:

[RESOURCE 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4343/how-to-create-calculated-tables-in-a-tabular-sql-server-analysis-services-ssas-model/)
[RESOURCE 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt637057.aspx)

Once the calculated table is created use my query and you will see the average of the last three months.

I've tested this approach using calculated columns and it works.

Let me know if this helps for you.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro.  Getting there.  Please see edit to original post.

Comment: @PaulEvans, is your input table created by using the last expression? Also what version of SSAS are you using?

Comment: Using 2016 with the latest updates.  Last expression is not used anywhere in the process right now.

Comment: @PaulEvans, What I undestand from your question is that your input table is not fisical, you produce it using some expression. Could you share with me that expression or a basic example of the fisical listings table?

Comment: Alejandro, detail on code and data added to original post (see below line of dashes)

Comment: Thanks for all your help Alejandro, I'm sure that will work.  Also just discovered DAX var's which may be another approach.  Lots of great new stuff in 2016.  Books I started with focus on 2012.

Comment: @PaulEvans, I tried with VAR too but unfortunately it doesn't work. It seems in-memory structures don't work with the same capabilities as fisical tables. I encourage you to use calculated tables. Also keep in mind a general rule for Data Warehousing, if you constantly require  calculated tables creation or intermediate structures, it could be an alert  pointing your model is not designed to supply your reporting needs.

Comment: Alejandro, tried a calculated table.  Started with very constrained DAX i.e. single area, few dates, etc. ... worked.  As constraints were relaxed ... quickly ran out of memory.  Also tried creating a simple physical table relating listingIDs to all months they are on the market.  This is 5X slower than current approach to compute monthly inventory.

Comment: Think I got it.  Check out the documentation for the GroupBy function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163693.aspx).  It's very similar to Summarize.  But you can save the result of a GroupBy in a variable ... then access the variable in another GroupBy and get to the "summarized" expression (in my case inventory) ... convoluted, but it works.